# Помогите применить метод dist, который принимает еще один объект класса Point и находит эвклидово расстояние между двумя точками

Tags: python, ооп

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо реализовать класс Point (точка). У этого класса должны быть
конструктор, принимающий два числа x и y, координаты точки на плоскости;
аттрибуты x и y через которые можно будет получить координаты точки;
метод dist, который принимает еще один объект класса Point и находит эвклидово расстояние между двумя точками.

Comment: вынесите из класса объявление p1 и p2

Comment: def dist(self, p2): return sqrt((self.x-p2.x)**2 + (self.y-p2.y)**2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def dist(self, other_point):
        return math.sqrt(
            (other_point.x - self.x) ** 2
            + (other_point.y - self.y) ** 2)


p1 = Point(2, 5)
p2 = Point(4, 6)
print(p1.dist(p2))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 2.23606797749979
> ```

---

Что вы сделали не аккуратно:

1. Не возможно продолжать определение класса, когда вы его окончили окончанием отступов:

   ```
   class Point:
       def __init__(self, x, y):
           self.x = x
           self.y = y
   p1 = Point(2, 5)                # Эта команда окончила определение класса
   ```

   Эту (и последующую) команду нужно перенести за конец определение класса.
2. В определении метода `dist()` нужен тоже второй параметр — точка (инстанция класса `Point`), к которой вы вычисляете расстояние.
3. В методе `dist()` не хватит только сделать вычисление, результат нужен быть в команде `return`.